# Bad results using Alchemy Api Sentiment Analysis

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I'm trying to get similar results with Watson Alchemy Sentiment API for Spanish sentences compared to translation results in English.

Here's the phrase (actually is a tweet translated from spanish)

"Lower tax revenues and increase electricity subsidy costs = disaster formula"

This is the result from Alchemy
Sentiment    Score
negative    -0.74192

Now same sentence but in Spanish (this is the original one)

Bajar ingresos por impuestos y aumentar gastos con subsidio eléctrico = fórmula de desastre

```
   <docSentiment>
       <type>neutral</type>
   </docSentiment>
```

What can be done to improve this, thanks for your help.

Comment: I would have suggested targeted sentiment, as that normally gives better results. However doesn't appear to be working for your Spanish text.